# Counting occurrences of 1 --> 0 changing for a signal in SIMULINK

Tags: count, binary, simulink

I have, for example, this vector coming as a signal from other block each

sample of time, let’s say each second. Actually, the nature of this vector is

random but this is just an example:

```
U = [1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0]
```

I want to process this signal to a block that counts the occurrences of changing

from 1 to 0. The initial value is assumed to be zero.

Therefore, in the above example, when the first two entries (which are ones)

enter this block, the block will give zero output.

But, when the third entry (which is zero and its previous value is 1) enters the

block, it will give me one and when the sixth entry (which is zero and its

previous value is 1) enters the block, it will give me two and when the last

entry (which is zero and its previous value is 1) enters the block, it will give

me three. For all other cases, the block will give zero.

So, the block will count the cases where the input is zero and its previous

input is one.

The output of the block is keeping changing over the time which, in turn, will

enter to other block.

I don’t want the implementation or details. I already know all of that.

I just want to know what is the name of the block that does such counting.

I tried using counter and memory blocks but unfortunately, I was not able to get

the right aimed results.

The

regards

Comment: you can use s function for this.

Answer (score 0):

No idea if you still require an answer, but the following should do it (I don't think it can be done in one standard block).

This assumes that your input is a signal that changes over time (and not a constant vector).

[Version 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6VvC.jpg) would, for your input of `[1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0]`, provide an output of `[0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3]`.

Since you wrote

> For all other cases, the block will give zero.

I also included a [Version 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFBWF.jpg) which will, for your input, output `[0 0 1 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 3]`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.